# Can I get return value prepared by powershell before returning from function?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to know the *return value* prepared by powershell before returning from function?

Pseudo code:

```
function Foo()
{
    1
    2
    Write-Host $CURRENT_RESULT # I would like it to print [1, 2]
    3
    4
    Write-Host $CURRENT_RESULT # I would like it to print [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a variable like $CURRENT_RESULT that I am aware of.  You could do something manual/ugly like this:

```
function Foo 
{
    $OFS = ','
    $r1 = & {
        1
        2
    }
    $r1
    Write-Host "Returning $r1"
    $r2 = & {
        3
        4
    }
    $r2
    Write-Host "Returning $r2"
}
```

You also mention wanting to know the values before the function returns.  Note that if you run this function and don't capture its output, 1 and 2 show up *before* the first call to Write-Host e.g:

```
PS> Foo
1
2
Returning 1,2
3
4
Returning 3,4
```

This is because functions behave like cmdlets i.e. they write to the output as soon as output becomes available.  So in this regard, PowerShell functions don't quite behave like a traditional function.